# Perl Regex Get token from string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string `$string: aa,bbbb,ccc,ddddddddd`.  I am trying to use a regex to return the tokens separated by the `,` character.

I tried this approach:

```
$string = "aa,bbbb,ccc,ddddddddd";

if ($string =~ /(..)\,/) {
    print "token = $1\n";
}
```

I got the expected output as 'aa'.

But when I try to generalize it, it doesn't work.

```
$string = "aaaa,bbbb,ccc,ddddddddd";

    if ($string =~ /(.*)\,/) {
        print "token = $1\n";
    }
```

What should I add to get 'aaaa'?

Answer (score 4):

[split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a good tool for this job:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "aaaa,bbbb,ccc,ddddddddd";
my @tokens = split /,/, $string;
print "$tokens[0]\n" if @tokens;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lazy `.*?`

```
$string = "aaaa,bbbb,ccc,ddddddddd";

    if ($string =~ /(.*?)\,/) {
        print "token = $1\n";
    }
```

will select `aaaa`

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "aaaa,bbbb,ccc,ddddddddd";

if ($string =~ /([^,]*)\,/) {
    print "token = $1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer would be to use `split`, but here are some things that might help you.

First, lets see what was wrong with your regex:

The `*` quantifier is greedy, that means it consumes as many as possible. To avoid that, you can use the non-greedy version `*?` to eat as few as possible:

```
$string =~ /(.*?),/ # $1 is now "aa"
```

Next, it might be saner to use the character class `[^,]` (everything but `,`) instead of `.` this way you don't have to think about the greediness of your quantifier.

To match multiple times on the same regex, you can use the `g` flag. `\G` (Match were the last match ended) comes in handy, too. I'm also including the case where there are no commas at the end of the string.

```
$string =~ qr/\G([^,]*)  # Capture everything but ,
              (?:,|$)     # Match , or the end of the string (and don't capture it)
             /gx;
```

So what could we do with it? Well, we could use it in a while loop or store the matched groups in an array:

```
while ($string =~ /\G([^,]*)(?:,|$)/g){
   say "token = $1"
}


my @array = $string =~ /\G([^,]*)(?:,|$)/g);
say "token = $_" foreach @array;
```

To store in capture groups in variables, you'll have to be careful to always use `LIST` context (put parens around the left side of `=`, or a variable nomination that starts with `@`, like `@array` (there are more ways, but those are the most general cases)).

Answer (score 0):

yet another way :

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "aaaa,bbbb,ccc,ddddddddd";
my @x;

(@x) = $string =~ /(.*?),/g;
 print join "\n",@x;
```